# Determine all local rings containing $\mathbb{C}$ and having dimension 5 as $\mathbb{C}$-vector space

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let $R$ be a local ring containing $\mathbb{C}$ and $\dim_{\mathbb{C}}R = 5$ (as $\mathbb{C}$-vector space).
>   Let $\mathfrak{m}$ be the maximal ideal of $R$ and $d=\dim_{\mathbb{C}}\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$.
>
> (1) Prove that $1\leq d  \leq4$.
>
> (2) For each $d=1,2,3,4$ determine all $R$ up to isomorphism.

(1) is easy, but I'm stuck in (2).

I know that $R$ is finitely generated $\mathbb{C}$-algebra and $R$ is Artinian.

In the case $d=1$, I think $R\cong \mathbb{C}[x]/(x^5)$, but I can't prove it.
In the case $d=2,3,4$, I have no idea. How to solve (2)?

Comment: Is this from a course of representation theory of algebras? It seems a bit broad without tooling like that.

Comment: Have you tried to see what happens when $\dim R=2, 3,4$?

Comment: $d=4$ is easy: then $R = \mathbb{C}[x_1,\dotsc,x_4]/(x_1,\dotsc,x_4)^2$. In general $R$ is a quotient of $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dotsc,x_d]$, in particular when $d=1$, $R$ is a local quotient of $\mathbb{C}[x]$, $R = \mathbb{C}[x]/(f)$; by localness $f$ must have a single multiple root, up to isomorphism $f = x^5$...

Comment: A useful tool is the _Hilbert function_, the function whose $j$th value is the dimension of $\mathfrak{m}^j/\mathfrak{m}^{j+1}$. (It's the Hilbert function of the associated graded ring.) The values of the Hilbert function add up to the total dimension, in this case $5$. There are restrictions on the growth rate of the H.F., due to Macaulay (search for "Macaulay bound"), in particular, in a very small case like this, the H.F. is unimodal---once it it decreases, it can't increase any more. So your H.F.s can be $1,4$; $1,3,1$; $1,2,3$; $1,2,2,1$; $1,2,1,1,1$; or $1,1,1,1,1$ (no $1,2,1,2$)...

Comment: Another useful tool is _inverse systems_, or at least my personal preference is to use those. See for example https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.03089. This deals with $d=11$ but you can see some of the tools and tricks there.